# Google Sign-In without using third party libraries

Tags: reactjs, google-signin

I'm trying to implement Google Sign-In in my react website. I'm following the [procedure provided by Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) (Loaded the Google Platform Library in my `index.html` file and added the meta tag) but as I'm using reactJS, when I try to render

```
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
```

it doesn't show Google Sign-In button.

I know there are bunch of popular libraries like [react-google-login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login) but I want to implement Google Sign-In on my own without using a library. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried applying Facebook's Messenger plugin to my React site and it worked as expected. Please check if you have the proper setup.

You can try looking at the Web Browser console for errors. That's how I dealt with my problem in the implementation. I missed the KEY part.

Comment: I checked it but there is not errors in console log.

Comment: Where did you put your Google JS script? Can you please show me how you did it? A repo would be nice.